# Validity of theorems using natural numbers and irrational reals together

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

I read in other posts (like in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151010/164699)) that the natural numbers are not definable in the first-order theory of the real numbers- That is considering just the reals within the context of a real closed field. But a statement like "a natural number greater than zero times an irrational real number is irrational" is certainly true even though it references both natural numbers and real numbers. Therefore, in order to prove it formally and others like it, is second order logic required? If so, can you provide the axioms that would be sufficient? Or when most mathematicians develop theorems like this are they just implicitly relying on first-order set theories with their axiom schemas?

Comment: Usually , the real numbers are constructed from the natural numbers : First the integers are constructed , then the rational numbers and finally (the most difficult step) the real numbers. Which system do you have in mind that can define real numbers but not natural numbers ?

Comment: @Peter I'm referring to the theory of reals defined formally as an algebraically closed field

Comment: @Peter also individual natural numbers are definable but not the set itself without the second order axiom that it is the set closed under all inductive predicates- or at least I think. That was my question

Comment: @Peter: Take the field $\Bbb Q$, which is simply the smallest ordered field, then complete its order, prove that this is still a field. Call this $\Bbb R$. It's a real-closed field, and therefore any definable subset is the finite union of intervals (a singleton is an interval: $[x,x]$; rays are also intervals in this context). Nobody mentioned $\Bbb N$ yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All we can conclude from the limitations of the first-order power of the field of real numbers is that results such as "Nonzero integer times irrational = irrational" cannot be posed in the first-order language of fields. But both "the field of real numbers" and "first-order" are crucial here: alter the ambient structure or the ambient logic and the situation may change as well.

For example, the integers are quite easily defined in the field of real numbers in either second-order or infinitary logic. Similarly, in a richer ambient structure - such as $(\mathbb{R};+,\times,\mathbb{Z})$, or less-ad-hoc-ly some appropriate universe of sets - the integers become first-order definable.

The question of whether "strong logic" or "rich structure" best matches informal mathematical practice is ultimately a fairly subjective one. One of the triumphs of early mathematical logic, however, was its convincing demonstration that there is little concrete reason to not use first-order logic coupled with an appropriately strong set theory. So if you really want to fit existing mathematical practice into a single formal framework, the slogan "Everybody uses $\mathsf{ZFC}$ even if they don't know it" won't steer you too far from reality. As in almost every situation, however, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is ridiculous overkill; a two-sorted theory of reals + sets of reals is already enough (basically, a first-order approximation to the second-order theory of the reals, via the usual shenanigans).

Comment: Thanks. Would an added predicate symbol $\mathbf{N}$ with the following axioms work? $\mathbf{N}(0)$, $\forall\,x\,\mathbf{N}(x)\rightarrow\,x\geq{0}$, $\forall\;x\;\mathbf{N}(x)\rightarrow\mathbf{N}(x+1)$,  $\forall\;x\,\mathbf{N}(x)\rightarrow\forall\,y\,x<y<x+1\rightarrow\neg\mathbf{N}(y)$

Comment: By "work" I meant be able to define $\mathbb{N}$